# Duplicata em banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados

Duplicata em banco de dados seriam linhas de uma tabela que se repetem? Ou seria algo mais complexo?, essa pergunta se encaixa no contexto de relações de banco de dados

Comment: Depende do exato contexto onde a palavra está sendo usada. Pode ser isso, mas pode ser outra coisa. Pra a mim a pergunta não está clara e uma resposta será um chute por falta de contexto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definição de Duplicata:

> Qualquer objeto, escrito etc. de representação ou função idêntica à de
>   um outro; cópia, reprodução. - Google

Acredito que esteja se referindo a tuplas, apartir de sua pergunta anterior, caso não seja ignore essa resposta:

> O corpo de uma relação em Banco de Dados é um conjunto; sabemos que em
>   matemática os conjuntos não são ordenados (isso significa que os
>   elementos são todos distintos).
>
> Observação: Uma relação e uma tabela não são a mesma coisa, pois uma
>   tabela pode conter linhas duplicadas, enquanto uma relação, por
>   definição, nunca contém quaisquer tuplas em duplicata. - Adaptado por: Vítor Subhi

Bibliografia e Sugestão: Date, C. J., 1941 - Introdução a Sistemas de Bancos de Dados /C. J. Date; tradução de Daniel Vieira. - Rio de Janeiro : Elsevier, 2003 - 8a Edição (Capítulo 6)